# some question of scheme(hartshorne example(II.3.2.4)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The ideal $I=\left<x^2,xy\right>$ gives a subscheme structure on the $y$-axis.
In Hartshorne's book, this one having nilpotents only in the local ring at origin.

But, I don't understand...

Comment: Please add more details.. For example, sketch the related things that you already understand..

Comment: dear Berci, I don't know why this scheme have nilpotents only in the local ring at origin....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $Z=Z(I)$ be the subscheme of $\mathbb A^2$ corresponding to the ideal $I$. Fix some point $P\in Z$, i.e. a prime ideal $P\supseteq I$. Since $x^2\in P$ and $P$ is radical, we have $x\in P$. It already follows that $yx\in P$, so we are dealing with the prime ideals $P\supseteq\left<x\right>$, i.e. the points of the ordinate (no big surprise here). $P$ is the origin if and only if $y\in P$.

Then, $\mathcal O_{Z,P}$ is the localization of $\Bbbk[x,y]/\left<x^2,xy\right>$ in the prime ideal $P$. We certainly agree that $x$ is the only candidate for a nilpotent in this ring. However, if $y\notin P$, then $y$ is invertible in $\mathcal O_{Z,P}$ and we have $yx=0$, forcing $x=0$! Only if $y\in P$, there is nothing that stops $x$ from being a nilpotent.